# Consultar un modelo de machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Soy nuevo en esto del procesamiento del lenguaje natural con redes neuronales y es por ello que he seguido este maravilloso  [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-keras-text-classification/), en él se explica como entrenar el modelo en **Keras** además de como ver el porcentaje de acierto en el `test_set`.
Lo que me gustaría saber es si alguna manera de yo poner a prueba el modelo con frases externas y no con las del `test_set` una vez ya esté entrenado es decir: que yo lo pueda llamar y pasarle alguna frase para que me haga la predicción de dicha frase.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

**Danielmagox** en efecto puedes predcir una frase que no se encuentre en tu set de test pero recuerda lo siguiente:

> La representación numérica de la frase que desees predecir **deberá ser la misma** que aquella utilizada en tu set de entrenamiento.

Esto quiere decir que si usas algúna representación como **BagOfWords TdfIdf, CountVectorizer, etc...** la misma la tendrás que aplicar sobre la frase nueva y luego predecir con el método predict de la instancia de tu objeto.

`model.predict(`*<"la frase que deseas con la misma representación que aplicaste en tu train_set">*`)`